# Set resolver on individual field with GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql

I would like to set a resolver, on an individual field that returns a string.

For this example. I want to take the `title` attribute, and make it `.toUpperCase`

#### Schema

```
type Product {
  title(uppercase:Boolean!): String!
}
type Query {
  products: [Product]
}
```

### Resolver

```
Query: {
    products: () => [{title:'foo'}],
    products.title: (stringToRtn, { action }) => {
    return action ? stringToRtn.toUpperCase : stringToRtn
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
const resolvers = {
  Product: {
    title: product => {
      return product.title.toUpperCase();
    }
  },
  Query: {
    products: () => [{title:'foo'}]
  }
};
```

If you're using TypeScript, use these `typeDefs`:

```
type Product {
  title: String!
}
type Query {
  products: [Product]
}
```

Another way is to use custom directive like "@upperCase", but it's too complex for this.

**TypeScript update directive way**

Remove `: GraphQLField<any, any>` if you're not using TypeScript.

`@uppercase` directive implementation:

```
import { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } from 'graphql-tools';
import { GraphQLField, defaultFieldResolver } from 'graphql';

class UppercaseDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  public visitFieldDefinition(field: GraphQLField<any, any>) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
    field.resolve = async function resolver(...args) {
      const result = resolve.apply(this, args);
      if (typeof result === 'string') {
        return result.toUpperCase();
      }
      return result;
    };
  }
}

export { UppercaseDirective };
```

If you're using TypeScript use these `typeDefs`:

```
const typeDefs: string = `
  enum Status {
    SOLD_OUT
    NO_STOCK
    OUT_OF_DATE @deprecated(reason: "This value is deprecated")
  }

  type Book {
    id: ID!
    title: String @uppercase
    author: String
    status: Status
    name: String @deprecated(reason: "Use title instead")
  }

  type Query {
    books: [Book]!
    bookByStatus(status: Status!): [Book]!
  }
`;
```

`schema`:

(Remove `: GraphQLSchema` if you're not using TypeScript.)

```
const schema: GraphQLSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  schemaDirectives: {
    deprecated: DeprecatedDirective,
    uppercase: UppercaseDirective
  }
});
```

Here is a link to [source code using TypeScript](https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-server-express-starter/tree/master/src/custom-directive)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem right. This would do `title.toUpperCase()` every time. I want to pass it an argument in order to determine whether or not it should.

Comment: Ahh I see the tricky part- it's with calling it the schema type itself. Strange that I can name `Product` anything I want- but not `Query`. I get it now. Thanks

Comment: @Ycon Update `graphql` `directive` way

Comment: Thanks- the directive way seems a little verbose for such a use case but very good to know